# How to return values from functions making HTTP request in node.js?

Tags: javascript, http, node.js

The getStockValue() function is called from another javascript file in the following way:

```
var r=require("./stockfile");
var returedData = r.getStockValue());
```

here returnedData contains only "-START-".

My objective is to get the body object returned from the function, ***after*** receiving the response. I've tried putting a return statement into the '**close**' event handler, but it didn't work.

How should I do that?

```
function getStockValue() {

    var http = require('http');

    var options = {
        host: 'in.reuters.com',
        path: '/finance/stocks/overview?symbol=RIBA.BO',
        method: 'GET'

    };

    var body = "--START--";

    var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
        console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
        console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));

        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;

        });

        res.on('close', function () {
            console.log("\n\nClose received!");
        });

    });

    req.on('error', function (e) {
        console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
    });
    req.end();

    return body + '... recieved';
}

exports.getStockValue = getStockValue;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As this is an asynchronous operation if will return straight away and continue to run in the background, hense why you only receive `-START-`. You can resolve this with the help of a callback function. Heres how:

Call the function as follows:

```
r.getStockValue(function(result) {
     var returedData = result

     //... rest of your processing here
}));
```

and within the `getStockValue` function change to this:

```
function getStockValue(callback) {
   ...

   res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        body += chunk;
        callback(body);
   }); 

   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks will try and get back to you! :)